# How to write multiple exceptions within a method when it is being discouraged in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

My code just looks like this:

```
try
{
   foo();
}
catch (SecurityTokenValidationException ex)
{
    Logger.ErrorFormat(ex.Message, ex);
    return null;
}
catch (SignatureVerificationFailedException ex)
{
    Logger.ErrorFormat(ex.Message, ex);
    return null;
}
```

But the code analysis reports `"Avoid Excessive Complexity"`

Any pointers ?

Comment: Just suppress the warning.

Comment: I don't why this should be called "nested". My guess would be, that you shouldn't return from `catch`.

Comment: There is probably additional code in the function that together with the shown code causes the warning. Do as the warning tells you: refactor the function. E.g. split it in two or more simpler functions.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with this approach *if* you're doing something different between your exception handlers. If you're handling all the types the same, then its unnecessary and may as well just catch Exception

Comment: @LDJ - only if `foo` can *only* throw those two specific exceptions. Otherwise, you are changing the behaviour (two exceptions are caught, logged and swallowed. All other exceptions propogate further up the stack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using **C# 6** you can restrict the handling to your two types with **exception filtering**:

```
try
{
    foo();
}
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is SecurityTokenValidationException || ex is SignatureVerificationFailedException)
{
    Logger.ErrorFormat(ex.Message, ex);
    return null;
}
```

So you don't have to potentially catch other sub types of **SecurityTokenException** by mistake.

Comment: Caution, using when was only added in the most recent version of C#, version 6.

Comment: @MartinBrown True, I'll add a note in the answer.

Comment: You mean C# 7. C# 6 came out last year. (C# 7 won't be released until next year.)

Answer (score 1):

You can for example simplify return statements, by using return null only in case something failed.

Here are some pseudo code examples:

```
bool success;
try
{
   success = foo();
}
catch (SecurityTokenValidationException ex)
{
    Logger.ErrorFormat(ex.Message, ex);
}
catch (SignatureVerificationFailedException ex)
{
    Logger.ErrorFormat(ex.Message, ex);
}

if(success) 
{
    return result;
}

return null;
```

Or another example.

```
try
{
   return foo();
}
catch (SecurityTokenValidationException ex)
{
    Logger.ErrorFormat(ex.Message, ex);
}
catch (SignatureVerificationFailedException ex)
{
    Logger.ErrorFormat(ex.Message, ex);
}

return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resorted to using an exception which is the base class of the above two exceptions.

In other words,

```
try
{
   foo();
}
catch (SecurityTokenException ex)
{
    Logger.ErrorFormat(ex.Message, ex);
    return null;
}
```

Both `SecurityTokenValidationException1` and `SignatureVerificationFailedException` derives from `SecurityTokenException`.

Now, code analysis is happy :)

Comment: This can potentially catch exceptions you may not want to catch if there are other classes inheriting from **SecurityTokenException**.

Comment: The C# 6 answer is better for this scenario. Uno's comment is exactly right - you might end up catching exceptions that you might want to handle differently.